# JQuery Line animation under Navigation Items (anchor tag)

Tags: jquery, html, css, anchor

I'm currently redoing my portfolio website and its very much a work in progress. I Came across a tutorial using jquery that allows a line to animate under your anchor elements on hover, which is pretty neat. I'm currently having two problems with it.

1. It gets the appropriate width and left position on hover, however when the hover is not active it doesn't seem to grab the proper attributes.
2. I'm not sure how to go about updating the active element so the line stays with whatever link was clicked. Currently the first anchor tag is the active element so it always animates back to that. I imagine i need to somehow have a click function that clears the currently active element and then applies the active class to the new active element, but not entirely sure.

I will provide the code below, but you cans ee the problem in action at the live site [Here](http://kylebinger.com)

Here is the code as follows

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <nav id="example-one">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="nav" href="#home">Welcome</a></li>
                    <li  class="current_page_item"><a class="nav" href="#featuredWork">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav" href="#caseStudy">Case Study</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav" href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
#magic-line { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px; 
    /*left: 0; 
    width: 100px; */
    height: 3px;
    background: #fe4902;
}
```

JQuery:

```
//Magic line

$(function() {


    /* Add Magic Line markup via JavaScript, because it ain't gonna work without */

    $("#example-one").append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");


    /* Cache it */
    var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

    $magicLine
        .width($(".current_page_item").width())
        .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

    $("#example-one li").find("a").hover(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();

        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        });
    }, function() {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });    
    });


});
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive, but I think this is what you want?

I think you just need to remove

```
function() {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });    
    });
```

That is causing the slider to slide back to the original place right away. Or do you only want that slider to stay when it's clicked?

Comment: Yes this is great thank you, solves the bigger issue i was having. The only remaining problem i have now is when the page first loads up the sliders location and width are off.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me, when I remove that section of code the line disappears entirely

Comment: When I did it I still had the old javascript in loaded, I deleted the comment since it was wrong.

Comment: Ah I see, well i re-uploaded the current code to the live site, you should see the welcome link as the active link, however when you hover on the welcome link the line grows about 10 or 15px, indicating to me that the proper width and position is not being applied onload for some reason

Comment: Yeah it's weird, when the page first loads the width is 140px but then it changes to 154px after the javascript has loaded.

Comment: Yeah its bizarre, I really have no idea whats creating that change

Comment: the last thing I can think of is trying to wrap the entire js file in a $( document ).ready(function() {
 
});

Comment: tried it and still no success haha, this is a damn weird error

Comment: I think the issue is with the paragraph font, when I remove that, it seems to line up. Maybe try adding that style to the page in the javascript file?

Comment: Hmm thats an interesting development, I'm gonna play around with it

Comment: weird i still couldnt get it to work, for now ive just hard coded the additional 14 pixels as an addition to the width, thanks a lot for your help im gonna give you the best answer